# A characterization of finitely cogenerated modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring with unity and $M$ a right $R$-module. Recall that $M$ is called a *finitely cogenerated module* if for every collection $\lbrace A_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ of submodules with $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i=0$ there exists a finite subset $J\subset I$ with $\bigcap_{j\in J}A_j=0$.

I need to prove the following result.

> If the intersection of every chain of nonzero submodules of $M$ is nonzero, then $M$ is finitely cogenerated.

I made the following proof which is not complete:

**Proof**. Let $\lbrace B_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ be a collection of submodules of $M$ with $\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i=0$. Suppose that for every finite subset $J\subset I$, $\bigcap_{j\in J}B_j \neq 0$. If $K:=\lbrace i_1,i_2,\ldots \rbrace \subseteq$, then $B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \supseteq B_{i_1} \cap B_{i_2} \cap B_{i_3} \supseteq \ldots$ is a descending chain of nonzero submodules. By the hypothesis, $\bigcap_{i\in K}B_i \neq 0$. This shows that every countable intersection of nonzero submodules is nonzero.

How can I prove that the intersection $\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i \neq 0$ to get a contradiction.

I need any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue by induction on the cardinality of the index set $I$.  That is, prove by induction on $|I|$ that if $(B_i)_{i\in I}$ is a family of submodules of $M$ whose finite intersections are all nonzero, then $\bigcap_{i\in I} B_i$ is nonzero.  You have already shown this when $I$ is countable.  In general, suppose that this is known for all cardinalities smaller than $|I|$.  You can then write $I$ as the union of a chain of subsets $J_\alpha$, each of which has cardinality less than $I$ (for instance, pick a well-ordering of $I$ of length $|I|$ and let the $J_\alpha$ be the initial segments).  Then $\bigcap_{i\in J_\alpha}B_i$ is nonzero for each $\alpha$ by the induction hypothesis, and these modules then form a chain whose intersection is $\bigcap_{i\in I}B_i$.

Comment: Is it possible to apply induction on $|I|$. I get used to apply induction on the set of natural numbers.

Comment: Yes, the cardinal numbers are well ordered so you can use (transfinite) induction on them.

Comment: Well. In this case (the case of using the principle of the mathematical induction), there is no need for proving that the statement is true when $I$ is countable infinite as I wrote above, isn't it?!

Comment: Right, the countable case doesn't need to be handled separately; your argument was just the special case of the induction step when $I$ is countable.

Comment: Thanks Eirc for your help.